# How to scrape all comments from a subreddit on Reddit?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm trying to scrape all comments from a subreddit. I've found a library called PRAW. It gives an example

```
import praw
r = praw.Reddit('Comment parser example by u/_Daimon_')
subreddit = r.get_subreddit("python")
comments = subreddit.get_comments()
```

However, this returns only the most recent 25 comments. How can I parse all comments in the subreddit? On the Reddit interface, there's a `next` button, so it should be possible to go back in history page by page.

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v3.0.0/pages/code_overview.html?highlight=get_comments#praw.objects.Subreddit.get_comments):

> See UnauthenticatedReddit.get_comments() for complete usage.

That function has *args and **kwargs, and the function notes:

> The additional parameters are passed directly into get_content(). Note: the url parameter cannot be altered.

Therefore, I looked at that function (find it [here](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v3.0.0/pages/code_overview.html?highlight=get_comments#praw.__init__.BaseReddit.get_content)). One of the arguments for `get_content` is *limit*.

> limit – the number of content entries to fetch. If limit <= 0, fetch the default for your account (25 for unauthenticated users). **If limit is None, then fetch as many entries as possible** (reddit returns at most 100 per request, however, PRAW will automatically make additional requests as necessary).

(Emphasis added). So my test was:

```
 comments=subreddit.get_comments(limit=None)
```

And I got 30+ comments (probably the 100 limit, but I had to go through them manually, so I thought 30 was enough).

Comment: ok, I see, however, I need to get `all` comments from a subreddit. I'm doing data analysis, and need at least 10,000 comments minimum

Comment: As the docs note, `(reddit returns at most 100 per request, however, PRAW will automatically make additional requests as necessary).`. So if you keep asking  for more data, it will fetch more.